# Making apple account without credit card

Tags: iphone

How do I make an apple account without a credit card. I've tried everything!!! I do not have a credit card to make an account but i need to make one to download apps.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't tried everything.

Chose **none** in payment information section.

[image]

Source: [Create an iTunes Store, App Store, or iBooks Store account without a credit card or other payment method](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204034)